# Работа со словарем python

Tags: python, словарь

Вопрос такого плана. python3-nmap. Надо выводить порт, сервис, версию. Не у всего находит версию, из-за чего вылетает ошибка. Надо как-то сделать проверку наличия ключа version в словаре и записывать в переменную значения. Вот мой псевдокод до которого я смог додуматься. Но что-то тут не так

````
scan = nmap3.Nmap()
result = scan.nmap_version_detection("10.0.0.4")

for res in result["10.0.0.4"]["ports"]:
    port=res(["portid"])
    name=res(["service"]["name"])
    if version in service:
        version=res(["service"]["version"])
    else:
        version=('Версия не найдена')

print(port+name+version)```
````

Comment: Вы можете аыложить понятный питоновский код, который выдает ошибку? А не это пседокод понятный только вам. А так же ошибку

Comment: Только учусь, так что особо не понимаю как написать красивый код. Это весь, что я написал. И написал непонятно что. Вот ошибка которая выходит. 
 21 ftp 2.3.4
22 ssh 4.7p1 Debian 8ubuntu1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 'version'

Comment: На это ресурсе не надо красивый, а надо какой есть, кривой, косой вечно с багами, главное свой не повторимый код который cмогут понять другие :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ress = [{"service": {"version": '0.1', 'name': 'qwe'}}, {"service": {'name': 'asd'}}]
# 1 try-except
for res in ress:
    name = res["service"]["name"]
    try:
        version = res["service"]["version"]
    except Exception:
        version = None
    print(f'{name} {version if version else ""}')
# qwe 0.1
# asd

# 2 dict.get()
for res in ress:
    name = res["service"]["name"]
    version = res["service"].get("version")
    print(f'{name} {version if version else ""}')
# qwe 0.1
# asd
```